# Updating a document in cloud firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save the server response in the client side. I want to add a field to an already existing document in cloud firestore. Here is the code that I am working on.I applied the same process in another project and it works fine over there.

```
public class Stripe extends AppCompatActivity  {
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    String d;
    private static final String TAG = "Stripe";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    Card card;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stripe);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final int a= bundle.getInt("Amount");
        System.out.println(a);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final CardInputWidget mCardInputWidget = (CardInputWidget) findViewById(R.id.card_input_widget);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmation_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                final int a= bundle.getInt("Amount");
                System.out.println(a);
                //final int a = Integer.parseInt(amt);
                card = mCardInputWidget.getCard();
                if (card == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Invalid Card Data");
                }
                pay(a);
            }
        });
    }

    private void pay(final int a) {

        com.stripe.android.Stripe stripe = new com.stripe.android.Stripe(getApplicationContext(), "*********************");
        stripe.createToken(
                card,
                new TokenCallback() {
                    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), token.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        token.getId();
                        Map<String , Object> dataToSave = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        final String token1 = token.getId().toString();
                        dataToSave.put("token",token1);
                        dataToSave.put("Amount",a);
                        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        String UID = mAuth.getUid().toString();
                        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                                .setLenient()
                                .create();

                        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl(" https://us-central1-deyapay-192704.cloudfunctions.net/stripePayMoney/")
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
                        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
                        executeForm(token1,a,UID);

                        db.collection("deyaPayUsers").document(mAuth.getUid().toString()).collection("Stripe")
                                .add(dataToSave)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>(){

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                                        d= documentReference.getId();
                                        System.out.println(d);

                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "error", e);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    public void onError(Exception error) {
                        // Show localized error message
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getLocalizedMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show();
                    }
                }
        );

    }
    private void executeForm(String Token, Integer Amt, final String UID){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://us-central1-deyapay-192704.cloudfunctions.net/stripePayMoney/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
        Retrofit retrofit =  builder.build();

        APIService apiservice=retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<PostData> call=apiservice.savePost(Token,Amt,UID);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PostData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostData> call, Response<PostData> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    response.body();
                    String dp = response.body().getToken();
                    Log.d(TAG,dp);
                    System.out.println(d);
                    DocumentReference dbRef  = db.collection("deyaPayUsers").document(UID).collection("Stripe").document(d);
                    dbRef
                            .update("TransactionId",dp)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>(){
                                @Override
                                public void  onSuccess(Void aVoid){
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Documnetsnapshot successfully updated!");
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener(){
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e){
                                    Log.w(TAG,"Error updating document",e);
                                }
                            });
                    Intent i = new Intent(Stripe.this,generic.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Toast.makeText(Stripe.this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostData> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG,t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But I am encountering this error -

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

This error was thrown inside the onResponse class at DocumentReference dbRef line.

The exception occurs here -

```
DocumentReference dbRef  = db.collection("deyaPayUsers").document(UID).collection("Stripe").document(d);
                        dbRef
                                .update("TransactionId",dp)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void  onSuccess(Void aVoid){
                                        Log.d(TAG,"Documnetsnapshot successfully updated!");
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e){
                                        Log.w(TAG,"Error updating document",e);
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: I guess you are accessing your "db" reference before it has been assigned, hence NullPointerException. You should post the Part where the Exception in your code occurs and mark it in your code with a comment so we see where it happens

Answer (score 0):

As per the 1st comment by @Rudiger, db reference is declared and assigned inside `pay()` method using the below code but not inside `execute()` method.

```
// declare and initializing variable
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

There are 2 ways to get remove this NullPointerException:

1. You can either **declare** `FirebaseFirestore db` as a global variable inside your class and **initialize** it in your `onCreate()` method as `db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();` before calling `pay()` method.
2. Or else you can again **initialize and declare** local `db` variable inside of the `execute()` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseFirestore db;` which you have declared globally is not initialized and is being used in `executeForm()` method and hence you are getting NPE for collection reference at this line

```
DocumentReference dbRef  = db.collection("deyaPayUsers").document(UID).collection("Stripe").document(d);
```

To avoid NPE initialize the `db` variable inside `onCreate()` method like

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

now your `db` reference is not null and wont give you NPE if used in any method inside your activity.